# Карточка RecyclerView не занимает все пространство

Tags: android, recyclerview

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему карточка RecyclerView не занимает все пространство.
Везде ширина установлена как match_parent.
Пробывал использовать внутри cardview и LinearLayout и  Constrainlayout.
Результат один и тот же.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ниже указан xml код

xml карточки

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/flag_country"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:src="@drawable/rus"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currency_name"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:text="@string/name_currency"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/flag_country"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currency_value"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:text="@string/currency_value_string"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/currency_name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="NestedWeights" />


        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_favorite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_star_24"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/purple_500"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/currency_value"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:tint="@color/white"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

xml RecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".presentation.fragmentFavorite.FragmentFavorite">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="ИЗБРАННЫЕ ВАЛЮТЫ"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textColor="@color/purple_500"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_currency_favorite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_curency" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Не вижу проблемы, всё пространство у вас занято. То что у вас пустует место после последнего `View` `btn_favorite` заслуга заданной ширины элементов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотри [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691150/match-parent-width-does-not-work-in-recyclerview) или [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35216125/recycler-view-not-filling-the-width)!
В англоязычном StackOverflow есть ответы почти на все возможные вопросы.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)